# User defined function in Access, only running once, not per line

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem with running a custom function within an Access database. Currently, there's a process in place to import new data, and assign a foreign key (ENTRY_ID) to -1 for all new rows. A separate process runs to change the -1 to the next number in an incremental sequence.

This is the function:

```
Public Function GetNextEntry(table As String) As Double
    Dim r As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Double

    Set r = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT LAST_ENTRY_ID FROM LAST_ENTRY WHERE TABLE_NM='" & table & "';")
    If r.EOF Then
        GetNextEntry = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    i = r![LAST_ENTRY_ID] + 1
    r.Edit
        r![LAST_ENTRY_ID] = i
    r.Update
    GetNextEntry = i
Exit Function
GetNextEntry_ERROR:
    GetNextEntry = -1
End Function
```

And this is an extremely simplified version of the query:

```
INSERT INTO DATA
SELECT GetNextEntry('DATA') AS ENTRY_ID, IMPORT.*
FROM IMPORT
```

What I expect to get back would look like

```
ENTRY_ID, NAME, NUMBER
1, 'account 1', '1234567'
2, 'account 1', '1234567'
3, 'account 1', '1234567'
4, 'account 1', '1234567'
5, 'account 1', '1234567'
```

But I'm actually getting

```
ENTRY_ID, NAME, NUMBER
1, 'account 1', '1234567'
1, 'account 1', '1234567'
1, 'account 1', '1234567'
1, 'account 1', '1234567'
1, 'account 1', '1234567'
```

It seems that the function if running only once for the entire group. I can force it to run multiple times by feeding it data from the resulting dataset, but then if I scroll through the data, it will rerun the function each time the row is redrawn to the screen.

This is my long winded way of asking if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm after. I assume there must be, because this seems overly complicated.

Comment: Is there some reason you are not just using an Autonumber field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is being smart; it does not realize that your function returns a different
value each time.

Try redefining your function as:

```
Public Function GetNextEntry(table As String, salt as integer) As Double
```

And then

```
INSERT INTO DATA
SELECT GetNextEntry('DATA', IMPORT.SOMEINTEGERFIELD) AS ENTRY_ID, IMPORT.*
FROM IMPORT
```

This way Access will think they GetNextEntry depends on a value from import and will get a new value each time.

Comment: That's true but I don't think it's going to solve the problem, since the function also depends on the *contents* of the table to calculate its return value.  When the function is called by an INSERT INTO query, the recordset it opens will not see any changes caused by the INSERT INTO query.

Comment: That's a valid point actually. I had not looked inside the function.

Comment: So, the function on the inside should be changed as well. Which begs the question, isn't this what Autonumber fields are for in Access?

Answer (score 2):

As mwolfe02 suggests in his comment, define an Autonumber field (Entry_ID) on the DATA table, drop the use of the function and let Access assign a unique value to Entry_ID when inserting data into the table.

Also, you should explicitly define the fields you are inserting data into and the corresponding fields you are selecting from in your statement. Without doing this you'll inevitably run into issues in the future if someone changes the ordinal position of your fields in either table.

```
INSERT INTO DATA ([Name], [Number], [NextField], etc.)
SELECT ([Name], [Number], [NextField], etc.)
FROM IMPORT
```